# Adding objects in ArrayList in iteration

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

Ok, I don't know why but I am thinking I am missing something very basic to solve this.
Here is my problem:
I have a method createPublisherRequestObject(String str) which takes string argument and returns a List of ReportRequest Object. Normally for a given String 65 objects will be created. I have another method getTimeFrameValues() which returns arraylist of string. Normally this method would return around 15 strings in arraylist.
So basically I would be iterating in loop for 15 times (Num of String) and then for each iteration, I will be calling method createPublisherRequestObject to create 65 objects.
At the end of this I wanted to have a list of 65*15 objects. Here is my code -

```
ArrayList<String> timeList = er.getTimeFrameValues();
List<ReportRequest> reqList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Iterator iterator = timeList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String string = (String) iterator.next();
    reqList = rj.createPublisherRequestObject(string);
}
log.info("Final List Size "+reqList.size());
```

But this returns 65

Please help!!!

Thanks,
pratik

Comment: Why did you use such a complicated for loop instead of writing : `for ( String string : timeList )`? By the way, string is such a bad variable name...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you go through the list, you're *replacing* `reqList`. It seems that what you're wanting to do is either `reqList.add` or `reqList.addAll`.

Additionally, if you already know how many objects you're creating per string, you'll get a lot better performance by creating an `ArrayList` of the appropriate size:

```
new ArrayList<>(65 * timeList.size())
```

Finally, since you're using Java 7, go ahead and use the enhanced `for` loop; it's much more readable:

```
for(String string: timeList)
    reqList.addAll(rj.createPublisherRequestObject(string));
```

Comment: @Marc Or become a cyborg like Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 2):

You're reassigning to reqList on every iteration. You need to append.

```
reqList.addAll(rj.createPublisherRequestObject(string));
```

Should work.

Comment: Cruncher, Thanks mate. You are the savior.

Answer (score 1):

You have 65 because you replace your `reqlist` with the result of the call to `rj.createPublisherRequestObject(string)` instead of using the `addAll()` method. So you don't add the elements but overwrite the content of reqlist. Therefore at the end the list have been overwritten 15 times and only contains 65 elements...

Answer (score 0):

```
String string = (String) iterator.next();
reqList = rj.createPublisherRequestObject(string);
```

here you are assigning the result got from `rj.createPublisherRequestObject(String)` to `reqList`, so at end of itteration you have the last reurned value.

Instead use `reqList.addAll(rj.createPublisherRequestObject(string));` which will keep on adding the reult `list` to the `reqList`, at end you have all the value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 
reqList.add(rj.createPublisherRequestObject(string));
You were not adding that's why it's returning last iteration value.